# Magento 2 CSV image upload from external url saves image name with full url path

Tags: magento2, product-images, csv, image-upload

Does anyone know why magento saves image name with the full path or url e.g `http://123.123.123.123/images/image.jp`g will save the image name as `http123123123123imagesimage.jpg`.

It doesn't seen right it can't be?

How can I upload image from external server with proper name?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's confirmed here a Bad Bug here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5306